# Losing 2nd dimension data of an array saved in .CSV and reloaded with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with the following shape saved as a 3-dimensional array
(7352, 128, 6)

I want to save my data as 6 different files based on the 3rd dimension of the array

The code I used is below:

```
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName1+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,0], delimiter=',')
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName2+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,1], delimiter=',')
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName3+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,2], delimiter=',')
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName4+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,3], delimiter=',')
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName5+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,4], delimiter=',')
np.savetxt(filepath+'/'+dataName6+'.csv', normalizedX[:,:,5], delimiter=',')
```

The shape of normalizedX[:,:,0] is (7352, 128) before saving them.

When I try to load the text with the following code:

```
def load_file(filepath):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    return dataframe.values
```

I get a shape of (7352, 1), I lost data from my 2nd dimension!

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you send us an overview of your csv file ?

Comment: And why do you use delim_whitespace=True when you specified that your delimiter is ','. You should not put delim_whitespace

Comment: That actually solved the problem when I set it to false instead, Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Ok so I posted the answer can you upvote it or validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `,` as a delimiter in `np.savetxt` so you should not put `delim_whitespace='True'` in your `read_csv` function